# Residual for least square scipy.optimize.leastsq() , optimum solution

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I know that there is an example of least square in scipy.optimize,but I am having real trouble with  **residual function** for more than three days. I decided to fully describe the problem. I found some other similar problems through the site, but I could not really figure it out programically and really confused in my case. I could not create residual function properly which fits scipy.optimize.leastsq **residual**. I am really stack..

This problem is exactly A*x=b problem. Let me explain it shortly:

**INPUT:**

- y - e.g.: y1 = dot(delta_1, array([x2, x5, x6]))
- x - 8 unknowns [x2, x4, x5, x6, x7, x10, x13, x16]
- delta - length.

**steps:**

- **function** f(x_m, delta_n_m), n - rows, m - cols.
- **residual** |b_n - f(x, delta) |^2
- **minimize** residual using scipy.optimize.leastsq(residual, x0, arg(delta))

I have function, residual, minimizer and INPUTS as well, But, I am really stack with my residual function.

**find:**
 - (x2, x4, x5, x6, x7, x10, x13, x16), so, I put all values in the code.

**codes:**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq


def function(x,delta):
        return dot(delta, x)

def residual(x, delta, y):
       error = y - dot(delta, x)
       return sum(error**2)


def main():    


  # INPUTS
  # Unknown values 
  x = [x2, x4, x5, x6, x7, x10, x13, x16]

  delta = np.array([1.76762035, 2.04349174, 1.25674742], 
                   [0.94873891, 2.01859342, 1.46348023], 
                   [0.83678402, 1.12030343, 0.92516861],
                   [1.43, 2., 2., 1.57])

  y = np.array([0.8353410485015903, 0.73620941924970962, 
                0.45428639186344633, 1.6180418445100002]

  x_init = np.zeros(len(x))

  result = leastsq(residual, x, args=(delta,y) )

  print result[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

Answer (score 1):

leastsq expects that the residual function returns just the residual, i.e.:

```
def residual(x, delta, y):
    return y - dot(delta, x)
```

Comment: Hello Christian, thanks! I tested that, but, What would you think about fixing `ValueError: objects are not aligned` without changing the shape of delta?? By the way, in the beginning of code, x factor should be disabled, coz it is unknown

Comment: Please fix your code so that is is runnable, then I will be able to look at the error messages.